# How to open a fragment from a notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-notifications

I'm writing a messaging app that makes use of fragments for various views. On the first fragment that is open, the user is presented with a list of contacts, and when he clicks on a contact, another fragment opens to show the existing chat window. This fragment is started with the following code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
msgChat msgChatFragment = new msgChat();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putString("userSelected", manageContact.getName());
msgChatFragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, msgChatFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
getActivity().setTitle("Message Chat");
```

I also have a notification to inform the user of incoming messages. However, I'm having trouble launching the intended chat fragment when the user taps on the notification. My notification code is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
String notificationMessage = "My notification message";
intent.setAction("Action1");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
  context).setContentTitle("My App")
  .setContentText(notificationMessage)
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
  .setContentIntent(pIntent).setAutoCancel(true)
  .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
notificationManager.notify(notifyId, noti.build());
```

In my MainActivity's onResume(), I have the following code to catch the intent:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
try {
  String action = intent.getAction().toUpperCase();
}catch(Exception e){
  Log.e(TAG, "Problem consuming action from intent", e);              
}
```

However, getIntent() seems to always return a null value.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You can put extra information inside your Intent that is fired when pressing the nofitication. When your application received this extra information, simply react to it and do not load your contact for by your chat instead.

Comment: Hi, how would I put the extra information such as the username, and how would the app react to this extra information?

Comment: What kind of information is required for the ChatFragment? Or is a standalone ChatFragment?

Comment: I realize that tapping on the notification actually doesn't do anything. I thought it brought me to the Contacts fragment because I was already there when I tapped on the notification. Anyway, based on how the fragment is opened, it seems that it requires the username.

Comment: Well, you can add whatever information you want to the Intent that is fired when clicking the notification. Whether you want to include the username or not, is your decision. That can be saved in preferences as well.

Comment: I modified my code to take advantage of getAction(), but I'm still having trouble with the activity that is launched...getIntent() seems to always return null. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is not correct:

```
intent.setAction("Action1");
```

You should use the following statement to indicate the willing of the intent (i.e. open an activity):

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

To identify the intent origin you can use putExtra function like that

```
intent.putExtra("origin", "incoming_message__open_chat")
```

Do not forget to enable receiving that in you activity:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
    <!-- This activity is the main entry, should appear in app launcher -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In your activity get the "origin"

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   ...
   String origin = savedInstanceState.getString("origin");
   ...
}
```

I have not the full solution but you should deep in this direction and read: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html